# How to include external css and font awsome in angular4 with angular-cli setup?

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am playing with angular4 with cli setup,

I strucked to include **external css files** and **font awsome** in angular-cli 1.0 stable version,

I followed these steps

create cli project-> include bootsrap, jquery-> seperate the webpack.config.json (using ng eject)->include loadash upto this working fine,after that included font awsome but its not working

So manually I add the font-awsome includes in webpack.conig includes even it's not working throwing error like

[image]
Please any one let me know how to solve it

Thank you

Comment: why -2, Is I am asking wrong question

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the package by using

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

and add the following entry to your `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
        ...
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "styles.css"
    ],
```

Comment: yes I did that , but it's nt working, Means it's not giving any error,but  not woring

Comment: make sure you provide --save argument

Comment: Did the corresponding folder get downloaded in your `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Do you get any errors when downloading it?

Comment: no,after installing I get fontawsome folder in my node modules

Comment: Make sure you use the option `--save` with double dashes. However, you can also manually add `"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",` to your dependencies in `package.json`

Comment: Just a guess, but please make sure that you restart your app when changing something in the config files.

Comment: yes I did that, I have follow these steps, create cli project-> include bootsrap, jquery-> seperate the webpack.config.json (using ng eject)->include loadash upto this working fine,after that included font awsome but  its not working

Comment: webpack.config.json includes contain bootstrap, jquery but not awsome, is this cause any problem

Comment: I haven't used `ng eject` before, but I suppose if you use it, you need to add font-awesome specifically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141609/discussion-between-soumya-gangamwar-and-alex-kucksdorf).

Answer (score -1):

[Officially](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) this is available for download or as a Ruby Gem.

If you like SASS, which is a good way to code, you should know that Angular2 handle .scss files out of the box.

Usually is a good way to use a package manager, so you can:

1. [Install RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/)
2. Install the dependency as presented on their site

> Add this line to your application's Gemfile:
>
> gem 'font-awesome-sass'
>
> And then execute:
>
> $ bundle
>
> Or install it yourself as:
>
> $ gem install font-awesome-sass

3. go to your component created by Angular-CLI and rename the .css file into .scss file
4. add imports to your .scss file depending on what you need from the package

> @import "font-awesome-sprockets";
>
> @import "font-awesome";

5. ng serve

Comment: what is with the minus?